# Calculating a proportion for a sequence of normal random variables

Tags: r, statistics, probability

I'd like to check if a sequence of standard normal distributions have the 95% of its values between -2 and 2.

To check this for, let's say, 50 standard normal distributions, I'm using `x=rnorm(50,0,1)` and then, to get the proportion, I'm using `length(x[x<abs(2)])/length(x)`.

I want to repeat this task a certain amount (e.g. 25000) of times to see the different results I get. Therefore, I use `replicate(2500, rnorm(50,0,1))`, but now I need a different code for the proportion. I thought about something like an `lapply()` with the object `replicate()` mentioned before as a first argument and, as a second argument, the function to get the proportion, but it doesn't work. How can I do that in a correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `replicate()` a block of code as well as a single statement. how about

```
replicate(2500, {x<-rnorm(50,0,1); length(x[x<abs(2)])/length(x)})
```

although I might write that as

```
replicate(2500, {x<-rnorm(50,0,1); mean(abs(x)<2)})
```

Additioanlly the `replicate()`+`*apply` combo should work as well

```
sapply(replicate(2500, rnorm(50,0,1), simplify=FALSE), 
    function(x) mean(abs(x)<2))
```

Comment: Great. I didn't know about using the curly brackets in `replicate()` for a block of code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This may work

```
# You already have done this:
x <- rnorm(50, 0, 1)
length(x[abs(x) < 2]) / length(x)
##  [1] 0.96

# Now you can do something like this:
y <- replicate(25, rnorm(50,0,1)) # Doing it with 25 "replicas" for demonstration purposes
colSums(ifelse(abs(y) < 2,1,0)) / nrow(y)
##  [1] 0.98 0.98 0.94 0.90 0.94 0.98 0.94
##  [8] 0.96 0.96 0.94 0.98 0.96 0.96 0.92
## [15] 0.94 0.98 0.92 0.98 0.96 0.96 0.94
## [22] 0.92 0.94 0.96 0.98
```

Other way, proposed by [aosmith in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067514/calculating-a-proportion-for-a-sequence-of-normal-random-variables/26067738#comment40842177_26067738).

```
mean(abs(x) < 2)
##  [1] 0.96
colMeans(abs(y) < 2)
##  [1] 0.98 0.98 0.94 0.90 0.94 0.98 0.94
##  [8] 0.96 0.96 0.94 0.98 0.96 0.96 0.92
## [15] 0.94 0.98 0.92 0.98 0.96 0.96 0.94
## [22] 0.92 0.94 0.96 0.98
```

Comment: If you switch to using `mean(abs(x) <2)` instead of `length`, you can then very easily use `colMeans`.

Comment: @aosmith Indeed! Including it now! (Learning something every day! I love StackOverflow!)